# Zend Framework 2 custom style for each user

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I am building an application for companies which sends anonymous-links to customers for filling out a questionnaire. The company should be able to change the colors and the logo of the questionnaire to reflect the affiliation to the company's CI.

My idea was to make a folder for every company (in my case, represented as doctrine entity Client) and load the layout's style.css and logo.png etc. dynamically from this folder.

The question: how do I implement this? How can I change a variable in the layout file from the controller? Or do I have to place the whole layout inside the view.phtml file for the ViewModel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**If I had to have several layouts depending on some condition.**

I would make the layouts for every company, set them in module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'module' => __DIR__ . '/../view/',
    ),
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/company1' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/company1.phtml',
        'layout/company2' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/company2.phtml',
    )
),
```

Then in gloabal.php or in the same module.config.php would add some options:

```
'companies_layouts' => array(
    'IDofComapny1' => 'layout/company1',
    'IDofComapny2' => 'layout/company2',
)
```

And finally in the controller would do something like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();

            // Getting company identifier
    $companyId = $this->params()->fromRoute( 'companyId' );

    // do something
            ...

    $this->layout( $sm->get('Config')['companies_layouts'][$comanyId] );

    return new ViewModel();
}
```

**If you just need to set css depending on some conditions.**
You can just do this in the view file:

```
switch( true ){
    case some condition:
        $css = 'file1.css';
        break;
    case some condition:
        $css = 'file2.css';
        break;
}
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet( $css );
```

And in the layout file you should have next line:

```
<head>
    ...
    <?= $this->headLink() ?>
    ...
</head>
```

Comment: Much more in-depth than my answer, therefore +1 for this one. Really good first post, welcome to SO!

Answer (score -1):

You need to set style.css and logo file path according to company name in you action and then you can access this vairable in you layout also as same as you access in view file.
And set you css with headLink() function. and assign logo file in layout header.

You don't need to place layout code in view file.
Write below code on you controller. you can also access style variable in you layout.

```
return new ViewModel(array( 'style' => $style ,'logo' => $logo));
```